# PHP: Change CSS attribute at specific time of day

Tags: php, html, css

So, I'm trying to write a simple function that changes the background color at a specific time of day, but something isn't working right.

When I run the PHP, the background color on the page is blank and the HTML has `background-color: ;`.  It isn't reaching the `blue` or `black` attributes and I'd like to know why.

Any ideas?

**PHP:**

```
<?php
function backgroundColor(){
    $backgroundColor = '';

    if (date('H:i') >= strtotime('06:00') && date('H:i') <= strtotime('20:00')){
        $backgroundColor == 'blue';
    } else {
        $backgroundColor == 'black';
    }

    return $backgroundColor;
}
?>
```

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <style>
        body{
            background-color: <?=backgroundColor()?> ;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo date('H:i')?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$backgroundColor = 'blue';` not `$backgroundColor == 'blue';`

Comment: @MikeW See "When I run the PHP..."

Comment: I think it would be a lot nicer to change a class on your `<body>` tags, rather than change the styles directly in the header.

Comment: $backgroundColor='blue';  $backgroundColor='black'; not ==

Comment: @DaveChen Yep.  I thought it would be something simple... Thanks!

Comment: I also recommend doing this in JavaScript instead. The timezone of your clients can be used instead.

Comment: Why is this being down-voted? This is a genuine question. The OP has provided code, he has tried to do something and it isn't working. He may have made a couple of noob mistakes, but everyone has to start somewhere.

Comment: Though I agree, I'd like to see less of syntax related questions.

Comment: @Jeemusu Too many over-zealous PHP coders... surprising considering PHP is such a "loose" language...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems. The first is that your doing checks to so if a time (formarted as a time, I.E. 10:13) is greater/less than a time formarted as a UNIX timestamp. This isn't going to work unfortunately. To solve this you should wrap your `date()` calls in the `strtotime()` method.

The second problem is that you are trying to set values using multiple `=` signs. In php you set values using a single `=`. Multiple `==` are used to check if a variable has a value of something. Try the below amended code:

```
function backgroundColor(){
    $backgroundColor = '';

    if (strtotime(date('H:i')) >= strtotime('06:00') && strtotime(date('H:i')) <= strtotime('20:00')){
        $backgroundColor = 'blue';
    } else {
        $backgroundColor = 'black';
    }

    return $backgroundColor;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the strtotime() function on the date() function to properly convert the two into equivalents.

Additionally, you were using the == comparison operator in place of the = set operator.

PHP:

```
<?php
function backgroundColor(){
    $backgroundColor = '';
        if (strtotime(date('H:i')) >= strtotime('06:00') && strtotime(date('H:i')) <=                strtotime('20:00')){
    $backgroundColor = 'blue';
    } else {
        $backgroundColor = 'black';
    }
    return $backgroundColor;
    }
?>
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        body{
             background-color: <?php echo backgroundColor();?> ;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <?php date('H:i');?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to bring up a grander issue with this whole idea. PHP is not a timezone aware language so doing this type of theme-ing using Server-Side logic will cause a lot of headache later on if you don't have reliable insight to your visitors location. Perhaps I could suggest a more reliable albeit entirely different solution to this issue using Javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function assignBackgroundColor(){

  var d = new Date();

  var body = document.body;

  if (d.getHours() > 6 && d.getHours() <= 20){

    body.style.backgroundColor = "#0000FF"; //blue

  }else{

    body.style.backgroundColor = "#000000"; //black

  }

}

</script>
```

Then just call it during the onload event for the body.

```
<body onload="assignBackgroundColor();">
```

Comment: I bring this up because I've done what you're doing before and it just wasn't worth it in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I've been looking at `date_default_timezone_set()` to set it to a default time zone, but it won't dynamically change according to the timezone of the current user.  I'll take a look at this JS.

Comment: Yeah you have to use some sort of location service to guess the time of the user based on their IP or prompt the user to give it to you. All of that infrastructure is sometimes ill advised when you can do everything you need reliably with some simple javascript.